# How to set a temporary cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How can i add a temporary cookie, so once user closes the page it should be expired.

```
function setTempCookie() {
       addCookie("temp",'');
}

function addCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}
```

I used empty value but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called session cookie and you can accomplish this with not giving an expiration date;

```
function setTempCookie() {
    addCookie("temp",'');
}

function addCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    if(exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }
    else {
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue;
    }
}
```